# How to add to EOD or EOT strings php new lines?

Tags: php

I am using EOD to scape the quotes and single quotes from a string but I want to display the string with new lines.

Here is my php code:

```
echo <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should not print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

And it turns out that the result it is the following (a continuous line):

> My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.\n Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}. This should not print a capital 'A': \x41

Comment: you're printing it out in a web context, which does NOT obey line break characters. heredocs and nowdocs both obey line breaks in the text as-entered, but the output/display environment DOESN'T HAVE TO. run the text through nl2br() or whatever.

Comment: Where are you echoing it?  If in a browser, you need HTML line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string =  <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should not print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;

echo nl2br( $string );
```

Of course, you may have some other issues, like HEREDOC not expanding hexadecimal, object notation needing brackets (maybe...) etc.